# SQL IF ELSE / CASE clause in WHERE condition

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, switch-statement, case

I have a very large MySQL statement looped through php foreach and each loop connected to the previous with union all. I will simplify the statement to the core of my problem, if needed I can of course also add more details later on request.

I have this table

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   ID   |   LANG    |   TITLE   |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   1    |    EN     |   T-A     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   1    |    FR     |   T-A     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   2    |    FR     |   T-B     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   3    |    DE     |   T-C     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   3    |    EN     |   T-C     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to write a **WHERE** condition in the SQL SELECT that should show me **for each ID maximum one result**. But it should show results **only if LANG is FR or EN**. On top **FR should be prefered** and EN should only be displayed as alternative if no FR is available for the ID. So the result would look like this.

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   ID   |   LANG    |   TITLE   |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   1    |    FR     |   T-A     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   2    |    FR     |   T-B     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   3    |    EN     |   T-C     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have tried to build something by myself with IF - ELSE / CASE but I am not very experienced with SQL so any help would be much appreaciated.

A simplified SQL I tried would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `table`.`ID` = 1
IF `table`.`LANG` = 'FR' 
BEGIN
  AND `table`.`LANG` = 'FR' 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  AND `table`.`LANG` = 'EN' 
END

union all 
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `table`.`ID` = 2
IF `table`.`LANG` = 'FR' 
BEGIN
  AND `table`.`LANG` = 'FR' 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  AND `table`.`LANG` = 'EN' 
END

union all 
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `table`.`ID` = 3
IF `table`.`LANG` = 'FR' 
BEGIN
  AND `table`.`LANG` = 'FR' 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  AND `table`.`LANG` = 'EN' 
END
```

Sitenote I may not use any construct with ORDER BY combined with LIMIT 1 since I am looping the SQL through a php for each loop multiple times.

EDIT: **SOLUTION that worked for me**

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
WHERE ID = 1
AND lang = 'FR'
OR (lang = 'EN' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE lang = 'FR'))
```

Comment: I wonder, is this for some tutorial or online course? I've seen strikingly similar questions in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant and efficient solution with a sophisticated query optimizer would be this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `table`
    WHERE ID IN (
      SELECT id FROM `table` 
      WHERE lang = 'EN'
      EXCEPT
      SELECT id FROM `table`
      WHERE lang = 'FR'
    ) OR table.LANG ='FR'
) t1
WHERE id = ?
```

This gives you the desired result, filtered by ID. In case the optimizer is however not able to push down the `id = ?` you might have to do it yourself to get decent performance:

```
  SELECT * FROM `table`
    WHERE id = ? AND (ID IN (
      SELECT id FROM `table` 
      WHERE lang = 'EN' AND ID = ?
      EXCEPT
      SELECT id FROM `table`
      WHERE lang = 'FR' AND ID = ?
    ) OR table.LANG ='FR')
```

However, if you can, I would get all the results at once and not iterate over the IDs in the first place:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT id FROM `table` 
  WHERE lang = 'EN'
  EXCEPT
  SELECT id FROM `table`
  WHERE lang = 'FR'
) OR table.LANG ='FR'
```

This will get you all the IDs that have lang 'EN' and no corresponding 'FR' plus all the 'FR's. Alternatively you could also try:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE lang = 'FR'
OR (lang = 'EN' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE lang = 'FR'))
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE lang = 'FR'
OR (table.LANG = 'EN' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table t1 WHERE lang = 'FR' AND t1.id = table.id))
```

But my guess would be the first query is fastest.

Comment: OP is asking for a query that returns only 1 row per ID. This query will not do that, as your outer query may return multiple rows for each ID in the inner query.

Comment: Ok, that was very not clear, since his example table consistent of multiple rows. But obviously this can just be wrapped into a select for the specific row.

Comment: I think your second select DOES give the correct result. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE lang = 'FR' OR (lang = 'EN' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE lang = 'FR'))`. It gives one result per ID unless there are duplicate ID with the same language. See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c167/6)./

Comment: If have to specify the ID in each sql since I am getting the IDs from an externale json_decode php script so I will test your last proposal even if its no performance optimized

Comment: @Fiddle: Unless I made a major mistake, all queries should lead the same results, just likely differ in execution plans.

Comment: @VolkaRacho: I would recommend trying all the 3 first queries just wrapped inside another `SELECT` like I proposed and compare performance and then go from there. Ideally, your DB would be able to rewrite queries like this automatically and push down the ID = ?, but if you're using MySQL then probably you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @inflagranti Your probably right that all statements give the same result but the OP stated in his first line he uses MySql which does NOT KNOW `EXCEPT`. That's why i showed the second select in a [Fiddle-link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c167/6) as an example. For the OP all those statements with `EXCEPT` won't work.

Comment: sorry if my feedback is taking quite long as mentioned i am not very experienced in SQL so modifing the not simplified SQL takes me ages due to the complexidy of the original query ;D I tested the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c167/6) but the problem here is that the ID is not specified and it give multiple results. I need a SQL were I specify ONE ID and get only one line of results. For each ID exist multiple LANG but each ID LANG combination is unique

Comment: I modified the fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/383ef/2) I think now it is doing what I need

Comment: thank you all for taking the time. have a good day and weekend!

Comment: Instead of looping the select you can also first build all the numbers needed and use `WHERE ID in (1,2,3)`. This would be faster. (added an answer for clarification)

Comment: I need the numbers in the order they are generated e.g. 3,1,2 that is why I am using union all

Comment: You're not guaranteed to get things back in order using union all though. See this answer to do it properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610945/how-can-i-order-entries-in-a-union-without-order-by/610984#610984

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where lang = 'FR' union
select t_en.* from table t_en left join table t_fr 
on (t_fr.id = t_en.id and t_fr.lang = 'FR' and t_en.lang = 'EN')
where t_fr.id is null and t_en.lang = 'EN'
```

Comment: i forgot where condition, first select is limited to fr. second select returns only en

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. I'll fix my down vote as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: This still does not give the right answer. See a [Fiddle-example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c167/13). You will get a 'DE' in your result.

Comment: @Rik yes, I added t_en.lang = 'EN' condition

Answer (score 0):

You can get your exact result in your question like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE lang = 'FR'
OR (lang = 'EN' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM `table` WHERE lang = 'FR'))
```

See [Fiddle-example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a527/16)

If you really want to give the ID each time you can do

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE (ID=1) AND
( lang = 'FR'
  OR (lang = 'EN' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM `table` WHERE lang = 'FR'))
)
```

This gives just one result per ID ([Fiddle-example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a527/17)).

You can also use multiple ID's

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE (ID in (1,2,3)) AND
( lang = 'FR'
  OR (lang = 'EN' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM `table` WHERE lang = 'FR'))
)
```

and build the `(1,2,3)` from your script and execute the select.
See [Fiddle-example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a527/15).

Answer (score 0):

for better knowledge of case statement in mysql

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html
```

for better knowledge of if statement in mysql

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ( LANG='FR' OR (lang='EN' AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE lang='FR' )))
```